# Alexa skill dies/crashes/quits occasionally with no error

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I'm developing an Alexa Skill hosted on an AWS Lambda.
Everything works fine with the skill most of the time, and there are no problems running it on the Alexa Developer Skill simulator page.

However, when running on an Echo Dot device, sometimes while processing a user response, the skill will just die/quit/crash for no reason, and no error is thrown at all.

Sorry I can't be more specific than this, I just wondered whether anyone else had encountered a similar issue, and whether there are any common "gotchas" I should be aware of.

Cheers.

Comment: Have you checked your CloudWatch logs for any errors?

Answer (score 0):

I would check cloudwatch, and maybe increase the lamda timeout / memory. The other thing to consider is your internet connection, firewall etc. I had experience something similar when my device is connected to a specific firewalled configuration.